# Repating Data when fetch or duplicate data when application running in each time

Tags: ios, sqlite, uitableview

I facing one issue , I store data in sqlite. I have two  tablviewcontrollers. On First Tablviewcontroller will show types , & on that type selection will go to second table-view controller which shown name & date on that table-view controller, But i run application in any time it will fetch or repeat data of second table-view controller, e.g. on second tableviewcontroller have 2 rows data if i run application 2 time then it will reflect data on cell four time, same data repeat or duplicate. Using segue i pass data . Help me why this happen. Thanks. 
code is : passdata

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"show"])
  {
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForSelectedRow];
    if (_segement.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
    EventTableViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.datais = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    _cellValue = destViewController.datais;
    }
  }
}

Second Tablviewcontroller FetchData Code:
-(void)addEventToCalendar
{
 NSArray *dir=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *dbpath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Calendar1.sqlite",[dir lastObject]];
 sqlite3 *db;
if(sqlite3_open([dbpath UTF8String], &db)!=SQLITE_OK)
    return;
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
NSString *select=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from Events where EVENT_TYPE='%@'",cellValue];
const char *up=[select UTF8String];
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, up, -1, &stmt, NULL)!=SQLITE_OK)
    return;

while (sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_ROW)
{
     NSNumber *eventsid=[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)sqlite3_column_int(stmt,0)];
     NSString *eventname=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1)];
     NSString *eventdate= [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2)];
     NSString *eventtype= [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3)];
     NSString *eventmonth= [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 4)];
     NSString *eventstetus= [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 5)];
     NSString *eid= [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 6)];

    [_eventidArray addObject:eventsid];
    [_eventArray addObject:eventname];
    [_eventDateArray addObject:eventdate];
    [_eventstetusArray addObject:eventstetus];
    NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@",eventtype,eventmonth,eid);

 }

  sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
  sqlite3_close(db);

   NSLog(@"%@ name array in update",_eventArray);
   NSLog(@"%@ date array in upadte",_eventDateArray);
   NSLog(@"%@ name array in update",_eventidArray);
   NSLog(@"%@ date array in upadte",_eventstetusArray);
  }
```

Comment: This post appears to be off-topic as per Questions that lack sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Please edit your post accordingly to add sufficient detail (code example from you!) so that people may help you.

Comment: @Amy here is my code please check it

Comment: addEventToCalendar where you called this method

Comment: on  AddEventButton  through which i adding event in calendar@RohitKP